# How to clear a textfield onfocus if it contain zero and onfocusout if its is empty then put zero?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to clear a textfield onfocus if it contain zero and onfocusout if its is empty then put zero?  globally in every textfield by taking class of the textfield?

Comment: what you tried till now

Comment: by using onfocus function in every textfield i can do but globally how to do..

Comment: Set your inline js into a function and bind it to $('textfield')

Answer (score 2):

You can use blur and focus

```
$('textarea').on('focus', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "0") {
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
$('textarea').on('blur', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).val("0");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/685eW/1/)

Comment: Was just typing it >.<

Comment: How it will work for textfield..

Comment: What do you mean with textfield? Do you mean a div? @user2790517

Answer (score 2):

Some of the responses listed here sound great but I personally wouldn't rely on JavaScript to solve this problem unless you absolutely need it to run on older browsers.

Both textarea and input fields have the `placeholder` attribute.

```
<textarea placeholder="0"></textarea>
```

This lets the native browser take care of replacing the value with 0.

Comment: This only works on IE10 upwards, so *"older browsers"* is a bit optimistic. Relying on Javascript for this is perfectly reasonable in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming by textfield you actually meant text fields and not text areas.

Catch them globally at the document level (or any element above the fields) and use a selector in the `on` method.

```
$(document).on('focusout', 'input[type=text]', function(){
    var $input = $(this);
    if ($input.val() == "")
    {
        $input.val("0");
    }
}).on('focus', 'input[type=text]', function(){
    var $input = $(this);
    if ($input.val() == "0")
    {
        $input.val("");
    }
});
```

### JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/chHfP/